# how to start a new terminal with agetty (not systemd)

Tags: linux, arch-linux, systemd, getty, agetty

For the sake of learning, I wanted to start a new terminal (let's say tty10) from the command prompt. I know I can just run `sudo systemctl start getty@tty10.service`, but I want to run it manually for now. I checked systemd service getty@ and it uses the following command line:

```
/sbin/agetty -o '-p -- \\u' --noclear %I $TERM
```

So, trying to replicate that from a terminal (tty1) I ran this:

```
sudo /sbin/agetty -o '-p -- <username>' --noclear tty10 linux
```

It indeed started a new login prompt at terminal 10, I enter the username but it never prompts for a password. Besides, when I go back to terminal 1 I see it logged out.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `agetty` should be in `inittab` or as `systemd` unit to persist.

As for `agetty` in a shell, it really was not designed to run in the foreground and control some other terminal, as mentioned in another post [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/512971/agetty-terminating-during-login-on-serial-connection).

Doing it as a `systemd` unit would allow it to persist with stability and not close the connection or the parent shell you used to execute `agetty`.

If you want to just check that you are able to establish a connection between a server and client you can do the following:

- On server: `# /sbin/agetty -L 115200 ttyS0 vt102`
- On client:   `# screen /dev/ttyS0 115200`

Where `/dev/ttyS0` is where your serial connection is. If you get a login prompt, the connection is good. For it to persist, has to be a `systemd` unit. For more info:

- [agetty](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Remote-Serial-Console-HOWTO/getty-agetty.html)
- [serial connection over null-modem cable (serial)](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/learn-to-use-a-serial-console-on-linux/)